# Angular 6. Access a "const" that was set in another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, momentjs

I have a `const` that was declared in another function. How can I access that value in the next function?

It's about the `const selectedDatePicker = moment` which I want to access later in my `getAppointmentTimesById()` function. I can successfully console log it, but can't access it later. When I try it with `this.selectedDatePicker` nothing happens.

```
  selectedDate: string;
  selectedDatePicker: string;

  onChangeDate(Date) {
    console.log(Date);
    this.selectedDate = Date;
    const selectedDatePicker = moment(
      Date,
      'ddd MMM D YYYY HH:mm:ss GMTzz [(Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)]'
    ).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    console.log('test' + selectedDatePicker);
    // check if a value exists and use it
    if (this.selectedAppointmentTypeId) {
      this.onChangeTypeId(this.selectedAppointmentTypeId);
    }
  }

  onChangeTypeId(TypeId) {
    console.log(TypeId);
    this.selectedAppointmentTypeId = TypeId;
    this.apiService
      .getAppointmentTimesById(
        this.selectedAppointmentTypeId,
        this.selectedAppointmentLocation,
        this.selectedDatePicker
      )
      .subscribe((data: Array<object>) => {
        this.appointmentTimes = data;
        console.log(data);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Why you add the keyword *const* when it already declare before? You can only assign (and change to a let).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `const x = ...` you're defining a local variable to that function, so you can't access it from elsewhere. What you want is to set the instance variable `this.selectedDatePicker` and that way you'll be able to access it from other methods.